# How to move the cursor by word in command line of tcsh

Tags: command-line, cursor, move, tcsh

I am stucked by this for a long time. How can I move the cursor in the command line of tcsh, as did by ctrl + arrow in vim editor, ipython shell, firefox, word etc. All these above can do this nicely, excetp tcsh, which is really frustrating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

For future reference, non-programming-related questions like these may be more appropriate at SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

tcsh has key bindings to mimic VI-style editing commands.  Just put this in your ~/.cshrc file:

```
> bindkey -v
```

You can then begin vi-style editing of previous commands by hitting esc.  Then, use "k" or "j" to scroll backward/forward in the command history.  Use word movement keys "b" or "w" to move backward/forward one word.  Use "cw" to change a word, etc.  When done, hit ret (from anywhere in the command line) to execute the new (edited) command.  For example:

```
> bindkey -v
> echo a b c d
a b c d
```

At this point, type 'esc k b' to recall the previous command and move back 1 word.  Then type "cw z esc" to change the word "c" to "z".   Then hit ret to execute the new command and get:

```
> echo a b z d
a b z d
>
```

Enjoy!

Alan Thompson